# EC2 instance launched S3 Endpoint subnet unable to list bucket object with endpoint bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I have created S3endpoint and added it to route table of a subnet. 
Subnet has route to internet and able to open AWS console. 
Next a bucket is created with bucket policy limiting access to it through VPC endpoint. 
I have IAM user which has full permission to this bucket. 
When i access the S3 bucket through S3 console webpage there is an error 'Access Denied' but i am able to upload files to the bucket. 
Does S3 endpoint imply that only access will be through AWS CLI \SDKs? and console access is limited?

Answer (score 0):

> Does S3 endpoint imply that only access will be through AWS CLI \SDKs?
>   and console access is limited?

My understanding is that any calls done in the AWS Console will not use the endpoint setup within the VPC, even if you're accessing it via an EC2 instance within the VPC.  This is because the UI within the AWS Console does not directly access the S3 API Endpoint, but instead goes through a proxy to reach the endpoint.

If you need to access the S3 bucket via the AWS Console, you'll need to amend your bucket policy.